# Converting Complex c function to fortran

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran

I am converting some c functions to fortran. In my c routine , there are two structures definitions like below

```
typedef struct heapnode {
              double c;
              int n;
                    } heapnode;

typedef struct heap {
                int n;
                int sz;
                heapnode *d;
                    } heap;
```

I converted above two type definitions to fortran as follows and it works well.

```
type heapnode

    real*8 :: c
    integer*4 :: n

   endtype heapnode


  type heap

    integer*4 :: n
    integer*4 :: sz
    type(heapnode), pointer :: d

  endtype heap
```

My question is about initiating of above two structures.  The requirement here is we should have one heap type variable and with-in that heap  type variable we should have multiple heap nodes.

To demonstrate this I show below c code to print heap elements

```
int i;

   FILE *f = stdout;
   fprintf(f, "Printing heap\n");

   for (i=0; i<h->n; i++) {
     fprintf(f, "[%4d]: n = %5d, c = %17.12lg\n", i, h->d[i].n, h->d[i].c);
   }
```

In above code h is heap type variable
h->n is number of heap nodes in heap variable h

Here we can see accessing heap node variables as    h->d[i]

I show  c code to create this heap variable and nodes below

```
 void *vspace, *oldvspace;

   heap *h  /* heap */
   heapnode *d; /* heap node */


   h->n = 0; 
   h->sz = 8;

   oldvspace = (void *) h;
   vspace = (void *)(h + 1); / * address of next node */

   d = (heapnode *)vspace; / *point heapnode to above address */
   h->d = d;  /  *assign heapnode to new node */
```

what we can see above is create a variable (this time heapnode)in a particular memory location and point a pointer variable to that.

I want to know , how we can do this using fortran. Could you please give me some hints to do this.

Comment: Your title is about some function. Where is it? Please think about a better title.

Comment: Alsovthink about the fact that people who might know how to do it may not know C. I think you should just make an array and avoid the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic is not available in standard Fortran. However there is a non-standard extension in come compilers called a 'Cray pointer' which will allow for limited pointer arithmetic. Note that Cray pointer arithmetic is not the same as C-style pointer arithmetic - incrementing a pointer to a derived type using a Cray pointer will not produce a pointer value equal to the original memory location plus the number of bytes needed to store the derived type. So statements like `vspace = (void *)(h + 1);` cannot be emulated exactly. If you wish your code to be portable then I don't recommend the Cray pointer.

Comment: The OP is already out of standard Fortran with `integer*4` and `real*8`, but I agree, Cray pointers are worse.

Comment: However, I think, one can just use a simple array, Unortunately the OP won't clarify, it seems. He/she wants to convert a function, but there is no function inhis/her code.

Comment: I agree that a simple array would be much better.